# Different behaviour of cd with multiple arguments in bash releases

Tags: bash, cd-command

Posting it here something that is puzzling me; upgrading an application server from Jessie to Stretch broke a `bash` script.

Upon investigation, we narrowed it to a change of behaviour of the `cd` command. I am not discussing here if what the script is doing is a good idea, or if it could be improved, I am just focusing in a behaviour change /awareness of changes mindset.

Jessie

```
$echo *-*
xxxx-1.0b xxxx-run
$cd *-*
```

cd works and cds to the first directory ; actually *-run is a symbolic link to the same directory.

Stretch

```
$echo *-*
xxxx-1.0b xxxx-run
$cd *-*
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

`bash` is 4.3.30(1) in Jessie, and 4.4.12(1) in Stretch.

Why the change in behaviour between Jessie and Stretch?

Comment: Also: https://askubuntu.com/q/905832/158442

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See the [Relase Notes of bash 4.4](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2016-09/msg00018.html), especially

> qq. There is a new option settable in config-top.h that makes multiple
>       directory arguments to `cd` a fatal error.

BTW, I didn't know. I just googled for "bash cd number 4.4".

Comment: Interesting. A Good Thing imho as it avoids silently discarding additional arguments when one has an escaping bug.

Comment: @spectras Interesting comment, while I suspected it could have implications security-wise, was not looking from that angle.