# What is the result of cd *

Tags: wildcards, cd-command

I tried `cd *` in my terminal (ubuntu), it changes my directory to the first directory listing

Comment: Likely related: [Different behaviour of cd with multiple arguments in bash releases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373625/different-behaviour-of-cd-with-multiple-arguments-in-bash-releases)

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 5):

`cd` is generally a shell builtin. So the behavior will be dependent on the shell, shell version, and possibly the OS you are using. For example, in `Bash` on `Debian 9` I get the following:

```
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

This is because the `*` is first interpreted using `globbing` and then there are too many directories and files in the directory I used when I tried this.

However, if I had only one directory, called `folder` in the current directory the shell would `glob` it into:

```
cd folder
```

This would succeed and change into `folder`.